# Script for upload multi images: the first image change the extension of the others

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i've this script for upload multi images. 
If i upload at the same time, the same type of images, for example, all jpg, gif or png it works well, but if i upload a mix of images types (mix of jpg, gif, png), into the DB i have all images with the same extensions. Into the foreach, the first image loaded changes the extensions to the others. This happens just for the DB because the class class.upload.php upload the images correctly into the folder.

Any idea? Thanks

```
    if($_FILES){

try{


$files = array();
    foreach ($_FILES['group'] as $k => $l) {
        foreach ($l as $i => $v) {
            if (!array_key_exists($i, $files))
               $files[$i] = array();
                $files[$i][$k] = $v;
        }
    }

foreach ($files as $file) {

  $query = "INSERT INTO gallery (img, alt_image, created) VALUES (:image, :alt, :created)";  

// prepare query for execution
 $stmt = $con->prepare($query); 

        $name = $_FILES['group']['name'][0];
        $ext = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $rand = md5(uniqid().rand());
        $post_image = $rand.".".strtolower($ext); 
        $withoutExt = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $post_image); 

  $handle = new upload($file); 
  if ($handle->uploaded) {

      $handle->file_new_name_body   =   strtolower($withoutExt);
      $handle->image_resize     = true;
      $handle->image_ratio_crop = true;
      $handle->image_x          = 720;
      $handle->image_y          = 630;


    $handle->process('../../images/gallery/'); 
    if ($handle->processed) {
         $handle->clean();
      } else {
      echo 'Error: ' . $handle->error; 
    } 

  } 
  unset($handle);


// bind the parameters
$stmt->bindParam(':image', $post_image);
$stmt->bindParam(':alt', $name);

$created=date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // specify when this record was inserted to the database
$stmt->bindParam(':created', $created);
   // Execute the query
        if($stmt->execute()){
            echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>Success.</div>";

      }else{
            echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Error.</div>";
        }
   }
}

    // show error
    catch(PDOException $exception){
        die('ERROR: ' . $exception->getMessage());
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not build the file extension always on the first element of the `$_FILES` array, but rather use what you've collected in `$files` on your own:

```
$name = $file['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

...additionally, have a look at some tutorials for debugging. They would've helped you to spot that error on your own ;)